# would like to install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

helo; we start again.
computer has an EOL (14.04) ubuntu and I would like to run a Supported Version.
everything tried so far has come to naught, including LinuxMint.
A fresh install is the desired option.

right then, we have managed to put the 'installation stuff' onto a USB, and can hold f12 on start up. This leads to a Boot Menu, which offers Options 2:, 4:, 5: and 6: [usb]
option 6 chosen.

"  Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot .c32: not a COM32R image
boot:  "

repeat repeat for a few minutes until it seems to stop repeating.
quite apparently it's gobbledygook and makes no sense to me

There must be a way to make this happen!
patience is useful, Please can someone help.

Thank you.

Comment: Linux Mint is neither Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) thus off-topic here.   You've provided no specifics as to the version you are trying to install, if a server/desktop/appliance release etc, nor ISO details which tell us which installer you're trying to use (currently Ubuntu is available using four supported installers, chosen by the ISO you use; you didn't provide this specific detail).  The issue "gfxboot .c32: not a COM32R image boot" is usually caused by a faulty tool used to write the ISO to your installation media, not the ISO itself.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: it's because the whole issue is messing with my head,

Comment: even when i press ENTER on here it takes me to a whole new comment! the grammar police are not too happy with that either!

Comment: it's really not too bad - it's all a great learning experience. learning patience hahahaha.    also, a difficulty with typing is that it is a very black/white polarised method of communication [can't even use italics on here] and it is quite difficult for boobies to be able to express the actual emotion that one is experiencing at the time of typing. {i've sworn at screen, just a few times - but not at your replies}

Comment: i've looked at so many pre-packaged answers that they are currently off-topic to me - especially when my post is closed down!

Comment: so, what ALL ALONG i have/had been wishing was for a quick, simple helping hand to guide me through the specific update-experience that was going on. I've not paid any money for help - it might be appropriate to do so, I don't know…cont...

Comment: ...I would dearly love to be able to make some positive contribution to this project - for the time being i am like a starving peasant - wanting to be given,  but really unsure (in the very short-term) as to how to give back. If this message can resonate at all then fine wonderful...cont...

Comment: ..if not, no worries. I'll just keep coming back until we either get this resolved or I'm booted off. so then i log in with a new name! and then the isp is blocked...cont...

Comment: ...Look fellas, we got a fucken WW in our midst and I would really appreciate having a decent piece of software with which to help make sure that, amongst other things, you guys still have a community and a happy healthy life. Cheers!

Comment: for the record I downloaded the latest release onto a USB stick. see you soon x x

Comment: FYI: Even *latest release* isn't really helpful.   The latest released version was 20.10, before that 16.04.7, which was an hour after 18.04.5, or a week after release the release of 20.04.1.. etc and that's just ignoring the dailies (20.04.2, *hirsute*)  I'm fully aware of when releases occur, but to me most people referring to latest should mean 20.10 (2020-October release), alas not on this site where end-users   usually mean 20.04.1 (4th latest release, but the latest LTS). Being specific is helpful.

Comment: and trolling me is not. I came on here asking a simple honest question and the post was closed. hence i had to ask the same question again - and it was bitched as duplicate. thanks. You've posted unhelpful comment after unhelpful comment, which will have prevented constructive answers. yet stupidly i still complemented you. i'm not interested in jargon-waffle; just wanted a question answered. bye bye.